# How can I create a local shortcut to an instance method?

Tags: php

In Python I can do this in a class instance method:

```
esc = self.super_long_escape_function_name
print esc(param1) + ", " + esc(param2)
```

In PHP, this is the closest "equivalent" I've been able to concoct:

```
$self = $this;
$esc = function($str) use($self) {
   return $self->super_long_escape_function_name($str);
};
echo $esc($param1) . ", " . $esc($param2);
```

and I wouldn't really even call that an equivalent. I also tried this without success:

```
$esc = '$this->super_long_escape_function_name';
```

Are there any good ways of creating a local shortcut for a class instance method?

Comment: Just a note on your second unsuccessful attempt - even if string notation conceivably worked for this (which it doesn't), you'd need to use double quotes rather than single quotes since single quotes in PHP always cause the string to be interpreted literally, dollar signs and all.

Comment: Although now it occurs to me that maybe that could be *why* you chose to use single quotes...in any case, the single vs. double quotes distinction is good for anyone learning PHP to be aware of.

Comment: @MattBrowne: That is indeed why I chose single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right after asking this question, I discovered that this works:

```
$esc = array($this, "super_long_escape_function_name");
echo $esc($param1) . ", " . $esc($param2);
```

This doesn't work in PHP 5.3 though, so I will accept a better answer if it comes along.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$esc = array($this, "super_long_escape_function_name");
echo $esc($param1) . ", " . $esc($param2);
```